# Can I use my Battlefield 2142 account to play Bad Company 2 multiplayer?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2, battlefield-2142

I had a blast playing Battlefield 2142 and all this recent hype for Battlefield 3 made me go out and get Bad Company 2 for PC.  I've tried logging in to BC2 multiplayer with my old 2142 account, but the BC2 interface uses an email instead of the plain username that 2142 accounts used.

Can I convert my BF2142 account into a BC2 account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and No - yes you can use your old EA account to play BF2 and no you cannot connect with your 2142 account. Before there were 2 accounts: EA account for game-support etc and 2142 account to log in the game. Now it is just one - EA account (your email address is used a login).

You can access battlefield veteran page and use your 2142 account to get a veteran status for your EA account.

Answer (score 2):

You should contact [EA support](http://support.ea.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You can try logging into the EA Account manager [here](https://www.ea.com/ca/profile/login). In the About Me section, you'll see your personas and "Other Identities" (which is where I see my BF2142 accounts). You used to be able to add/remove them from there but I can't seem to figure out how right now, maybe it's disabled because of this Origin account switching thing they're doing.